# End points of function is cluster point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

let $f\colon \Bbb (a,b) \to \Omega$ be a function where $\Omega$ is the extended of real line. Define $h(x)=f(x) \ \text{on} \ (a,b)$ and $h(x)=0 \ \text{otherwise}.$ Let $0$ be a cluster point of $h$ at the endpoint, that is, for all open set open set $U$ with $0\in U$ and every open set $(c,d)$ and $a\in (c,d) $ we have $$h^{-1}(U)\cap (c,d)\neq\emptyset$$  In the same we can define that $0$ is cluster of $h$ at $b.$ I do have two question :

(1) If $h(r_1)<h(r_2)$ and $r_1<r_2$.  Do there exist $x,y$ in $(a,b)$ with $x<y$ such that $h(r_1)<h(x)<h(y)<h(r_2);$

(2)  Can we say there exists  a sequence $x_n$ in $(a,b)$ such that $x_n \rightarrow a $  and $h(x_n)\to h(a)$ ? I know this is true in case $f$ has a dense graph.

For (1), Assume $h(r_1)=0 $ and $h(r_2)>0$. Now, since $a\in (r_1,r_2)$ and for each open set open set $U$ and $0\in U$, we have $$ h^{-1}(U)\cap (r_1,r_2)\neq\emptyset.$$ Then there exists $c,d\in (r_1,r_2)$ such that $h(c), h(d)\in U$ but I did not see why $h(c)$ and $h(d)$ must be different.

For (2), I have no idea if it is correct or not.

Lastly, my general question : How the cluster point of function at the end point is important  in some cases?

Comment: are you sure you mean $h(x)=0$ always?

Comment: @supinf, Thank you. I fixed. what do you think about it now ?

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$
h(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  1 &:& x\in(0,1)
  \\
  0 &:& x\not\in(0,1)
\end{cases}
$$
with $a=0$ and $b=1$
should be a counterexample for both (1) and (2).

The function $h$ should have
a cluster point $0$ according to the definition that was provided:
If $U$ is an open neighborhood of $0$ and $c,d$ are numbers with $a=0\in(c,d)$
then we have
$h(0)=0$ and therefore $0\in (c,d)$ and $0\in h^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: supinf, Does you your function $h$ have cluster point in endpoints?

Comment: @00GB I think so. I added an explanation.

Comment: supinf, your function as any function , no more conditions in it. So, any function like that would cluster point in end point. I do not think so . even in your explanation what do you mean $a=0$

Comment: Brian M. Scott, Do have an idea ?

Comment: @00GB I have chosen $a=0$ in my example. The interval $(a,b)$ is $(0,1)$ here.